# Dimension is not getting updated when deployed after renaming the dimensions & Attributes

Tags: ssas, analysis, cube, dimensions, msbi

I created 3 dimensions each with 3-5 attributes where one attribute having hierarchy. it worked perfectly.

But client came up with requirement that they want to rename  (let's say adding suffix as 'Structure' making new name 'XYZ - Structure') all 3 dimensions and for attributes which has hierarchy.

I renamed all 3 dimensions, respective attributes, taken care of relationship under dimensions usages, also renamed wherever it was defined under calculation tab, added into correct perspectives.

And I also changed ID of dimensions ( right click--view code--replace old ID with current name) and then added DB dimension as cube dimension in the cube designer.

built successfully, deployed and processed. But New changes are not reflecting. it is still showing old dimensions.

I tried couple of more things but not sure about this weird behavior.  Can anyone help me with any suggestion / guidance /tricks -n-tips /comments.

Any small comments towards this will be a great help.

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have any perspectives set ? (it may have a different Caption). Also, more simply, are you looking at the right Server / Database / Cube ? (cross check where the Cube is deployed ?)  The other thing, I could think of is -- do you have translations / looking at the right language ?

Comment: Thanks Subbu for your response, as mentioned I verified and added to correct perspectives. there is no Translations. server & DB for deployment is correct. I also have checked I have selected 'Full' as processing option. but no luck till now.